# Не работает регулярное выражение со значением полученным из FormControl

Tags: typescript

Вот код

```
  public phoneNumber: string = "31031234567";

  phoneForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    phoneFormControl: new FormControl('8356532235', [
      Validators.required ]),
      ...
  });

  get phoneFormControl() { return this.phoneForm.get('phoneFormControl')!; }

  next() {
    let regexpPhone: RegExp = /^[0-9]{10}$/;

    if (this.phoneForm.value == null) {      return;    }

    this.phoneNumber = this.phoneForm.value;
    console.log("phoneNumber= " , this.phoneNumber);

    alert( regexpPhone.test(this.phoneNumber) );    
  }
```

Сохраняю в переменной phoneNumber строку из формы ввода.

phoneNumber типа string

В консоль выводится то, что было введено в форме.
Но при проверке его с помощью regexpPhone.test() всегда получаю false.

Comment: false, потому что у тебя phoneNumber 11 чисел, а в regexpPhone строго 10

Comment: Нет, на форме я ввожу 10 чисел. Там для этого тоже используется проверка